# exclude a value in case statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a drop down with values: `All`, `Scheduled`, `Complete` and `In Progress`. Now I want to filter using `All` but want to exclude `schedule` in it. I am using the following `CASE` expression as:

```
tClientInteractions.FollowUpStatus =    
case @ScheduledStatus
when 'All' then ('Complete','In Progress')
else @ScheduledStatus
end
```

how to exclude Scheduled from All.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Could you provide sample data and the expected output.

Comment: i have a field called FollowUpStatus which holds values  Scheduled,complete and In progress. now i want to filter using all which will display complete and In progress results excluding Scheduled records.

Comment: Assuming this code is in your WHERE clause I'd avoid using CASE, I've provided an alternative as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `CASE` expression. Try something like this;

```
WHERE (@ScheduledStatus = 'All' AND FollowUpStatus <> 'Scheduled')
OR @ScheduledStatus = FollowUpStatus
```

The logic being that if you pass `'All'` as the `parameter` then it will return all `FollowUpStatus` that aren't `'Scheduled'`, otherwise it's going to return the value that's passed through.

The advantage of this is that you're not calculating in your `WHERE` clause which should help the performance.

To break this down;

```
WHERE (@ScheduledStatus = 'All' AND FollowUpStatus <> 'Scheduled')
```

Here, if you pass 'All' as the `parameter` then you want to return everything from `FollowUpStatus` that isn't `'Scheduled'`.

```
OR @ScheduledStatus = FollowUpStatus
```

This then says that if you don't pass `'All'` as the `parameter` then you must have picked a different value (`'Scheduled'`, `'Complete'` or `'In Progress'`). Only return records where `FollowUpStatus` equals this value.

Comment: but rich..i dont have 'All' value in table.so how it will filter only complete and In progress records?

Comment: The first part of the logic is checking if the parameter is set to 'All', not the table. If the parameter = 'All' then return everything from the table where FollowUpStatus is not 'Scheduled'. The second part of the logic then says that if the parameter is not 'All' (which means you have selected a particular value) then you want to return only the rows where FollowUpStatus = your value in the parameter.

Comment: @AB4U I've expanded on my answer to try to explain it further, let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to achieve your result :

```
IF @ScheduledStatus = 'All'
BEGIN 
    tClientInteractions.FollowUpStatus = Your_Statement
    WHERE Your_Condition
END 
ELSE
  tClientInteractions.FollowUpStatus = @ScheduledStatus 
  WHERE Your_Condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `AND/OR` logic

```
WHERE  ( tClientInteractions.FollowUpStatus IN ( 'Complete', 'In Progress' )
         AND @ScheduledStatus = 'All' )
        OR ( tClientInteractions.FollowUpStatus = @ScheduledStatus )
```